# Fill the array with extracted number from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I want to read numbers from a file and put them in an array. The **problem** is that, although the numbers extracted correctly, they **could't save into array**. It means the array is empty after the execution of program. I should mention that this code uses by a thread. 
Here is the code:

```
int ordercount=0;
//initialize
int Order[10]={0};
int Credit[10]={50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50};
//For reading a file
FILE *myfile;
//Semaphore
pthread_mutex_t mtx;
char char_get;



void *orders(void *arg)
{
///////////////////////////////////////////read from a file
    myfile=fopen("List.txt","r+");
    int k=0;
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        fscanf (myfile, "%d", &k);
        while (!feof (myfile))
        {
            ordercount++;
            Order[k]=k;
            printf("The initial Order is: %d \n",Order[k]);
            fscanf (myfile, "%d", &k);
        }
        fclose (myfile);
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

}
```

Comment: `Order[k]=k;` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: you don't use `ordercount`, just storing items at random locations in your array...

Comment: @stark: Thanks for responding, I want to use it in another thread to calculate some thing.

Comment: This is one of the rare proper uses of `feof`, but perhaps better is `while (fscanf (myfile, "%d", &k) == 1) { ... }` which will also check the `int` was given a numeric value.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for responding, I use it in another thread.

Comment: in your file List.txt the numbers are greater than 10 right? then you have undefined behaviour because you're using the values as indices for `Order`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes that is right they are in from 1 to 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop you're reading integer values stored in `k`:

```
fscanf (myfile, "%d", &k);
```

in the same loop you're assigning `k` to your list

```
    ordercount++;
    Order[k]=k;
```

but instead of using `ordercount` (which is too high by one because it is incremented before array access BTW), you're using `k` as your index.

If the values are higher than 10, you're storing data outside `Order` reserved memory: undefined behaviour.

(note that your `printf("The initial Order is: %d \n",Order[k]);` statement seem to work because it's right after the assignment, and it does not show the order where you store `k`: you have the illusion that it is contiguous storage, whereas it's not)

I would rewrite that like this:

```
    // don't perform the initial fscanf, do/while avoids that
    do
    {
        if (fscanf (myfile, "%d", &k)!=1)
        {
           printf("parsing error\n"); // maybe should exit if error?
        }
        printf("The initial Order is: %d @ %d \n",k,ordercount);
        Order[ordercount++]=k; // filling with values with increasing index, not random
    }
    while (!feof (myfile) || ordercount==sizeof(Order)/sizeof(Order[0]));
```

(using `do/while` and protection against too many values in the file)

Comment: Ok you are right but, the problem is that the array can not be filled. How your solution helps this issue?

Comment: the array is filled, but sparsely, not contiguously. check my edit for a fix.